# Show that any smooth projective curve of genus zero over a field $K$ is isomorphic to a plane conic over $K$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry

I have the following question:

> Show that any smooth projective curve of genus zero over a field $K$ is isomorphic to a plane conic over $K$.

Assuming that a plane conic is a conic cut by a plane, but I don't see
how can I get a hyperbolic by cutting the conic. Is the definition of plane conic correct? If it does, then anyone can give me a hint, please?

Comment: Ordinarily, this requires some background in algebraic curves or Riemann surfaces to solve. It is a standard exercise at that point. What is your background and where did you get the question?

Comment: @TedShifrin It's the question 2a from the qualifying exam [Harvard University, 2002]. I'm familiarezed with Riemann manifolds.

Comment: You probably want the Riemann-Roch Theorem. Riemannian manifolds is something totally different.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the hint. By the way, do you know what is the exact definition of plane conic? I suppose that is not the same that conic section, right?

Comment: It's the zero-locus of a homogeneous polynomial  of degree $2$ in three variables with coefficients in $K$.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Liu, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, prop 7.4.1 p285.

The idea is use the Riemann-Roch theorem in order to show that the anticanonical divisor of the curve $C$ induces a closed immersion $C \hookrightarrow \mathbf{P}^2_K$. Thus $C$ is isomorphic to a plane curve $C'$. This curve is defined by a homogeneous polynomial of some degree $d$. But the genus formula says $0=g(C') = \dfrac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}$. Therefore $C'$ is a plane conic.

Comment: This proof may not be complete. Because d=1 is also a solution to the genus-degree formula.

Comment: Ok but if $d=1$ then $C'$ is just a line in $\mathbf{P}^2$, so $C'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}^1$, which is in turn isomorphic to a plane conic (for example with equation $z^2 = xy$).